# Create furthest point in multilineString

Tags: postgis

I am very new to PostGIS. I have a table with **sections** (**multilineString**) drawed on a map and a table with **observations** (**point**).

Users can make observations and I have to automatically place the point on the section.

My first try was to use ST_Centroid to place the observations in the middle of the section and it technically works.

Unfortunately, it is not usable later. I print all observations on a map, and they all have same positions, so the top observation only is visible and clickable.

**I would like to create the furthest new point from existings points that is still in the multilineString (So it will naturally distribute on the multilineString)**

So for exemple:

- 1st point         : Center
- 2nd and 3rd point : begin or end of
  multilineString (0% or 100% lenght of the section)
- 4th and 5th      : 25% or 75% length of the section
- etc.

**I don't need to find the 1st observation, only the followings.**

[image: Desired output]

I saw a lot of resources saying that we should use ST_Distance DESC but it's not working as my points are new and not already in the database.

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.
Count number of points you need to place on a line,
and generate them by ST_Line_Interpolate_Point
with fraction equal to 0, 1/(n-1), 2/(n-1), ... 1.

Comment: Good start but doesn't work unfortunately because I'm using multilineString. It only works with lineString or with connected lineString (with combination of st_linemerge and st_makeline).

Comment: Maybe try to split it using ST_Dump into linestrings, and distribute points among lines proportionally to their lengths. But it is getting complicated.

Comment: I finally used ST_GENERATEPOINTS(ST_BUFFER(ST_SetSRID(<Section.geom Column>, 4326)::geography, 10)::geometry, 1). It doesn't distribute proportionally, but it ditribute randomly in a perimeter of 10 meters from my section. Normally, I won't have many observations points on the exact same position (unless there are too much and I'm not lucky). Thank you for your time and answers. And I valide your answer as I think it can help others people as long as they don't use MultilineString :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your observations are point geometry. If that's the case you can use ST_ClosestPoint to find the closest point on line and plot them on line itself.

```
    SELECT ST_ClosestPoint(
    ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING ((10 10, 40 50), (20 20, 50 20, 50 60, 20 20))'),
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(20 40)')
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. Yes, my observations are point geometry. But with ClosestPoint, I'll have the opposite about what I need no ? Actually, I'd like to find the Furthest localisation (too bad, function doesn't exist) on my multilineString from the others points.